# NewtonSoft.Json error

Tags: c#

Hi I'm quite new to C# and I'm trying to make a text editor that saves and loads Plaintext formats. I've used NewtonSoft.Json NuGet package, but I'm getting an error. I've stated a string called textToLoad, which is set to a JsonConvert.DeserializeObject. Only thing is, it says it can't convert an object to a string! I tried toString(); but it still had the same error.

Comment: Please share your code. Then we can probably take a look.

Comment: Maybe your data class needs to implement the ISerializable-interface? https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As error says `it can't convert an object to a string`.  the parameter to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` should be a real *json string* not an object. Seems like you want to *Serialize* the object not *Deserialize*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is kind of hard without the code. The process of serializing and deserializing is pretty straight forward using Json.Net. So this is an example from their [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm):

```
YourType yourObject= new YourType();
yourObject.Property="something";
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject);
//For some reason you want this to be string, but is the type you serialized in the first place
YourType textToLoad= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourType>(output);
```

This outlines the basic works of serializing and deserializing. But we don't really know the details of your implementation.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks I didn't state to file to set as the deserialized :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't deserialize into a string like that. At simplest form you started with JSON in the form of:

```
{ value: "someString" }
```

If you want something out of it, you must deserialize and then get the value from it.

```
dynamic foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(theJson);
var textToLoad = foo.value.ToString();
```

You must deserialize to something in order to inspect and get properties from it.

[Edit] - Perhaps I'm not understanding. But if you share code, I'll update my answer.